# QGIS Python Scripting permission denied

Tags: pyqgis

I've just started a Python Scripting [tutorial](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/getting_started_with_pyqgis.html) on QGIS. The problem arrives right at the end, when I have to use this script:

```
output_file = open('c:/Users/Ujaval/Desktop/airports.txt', 'w')
for f in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = f.geometry()
  line = '%s, %s, %f, %f\n' % (f['name'], f['iata_code'],
          geom.asPoint().y(), geom.asPoint().x())
  unicode_line = line.encode('utf-8')
  output_file.write(unicode_line)
output_file.close()
```

Please note that the PATH used is another one, and that's my big problem as I tried several alternatives on how to write it, examples:

```
output_file = open('D:\ne_10m_airports', 'w')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('w') or filename: 'D:\ne_10m_airports'

output_file = open('C://Users//Florin//Desktop//ne_10m_airports', 'w')
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C://Users//Florin//Desktop//ne_10m_airports'

output_file = open('C:/Users/Florin/Desktop/ne_10m_airports', 'w')

output_file = open('C:\Users\Florin\Desktop\ne_10m_airports', 'w')
```

I can't really seem to figure out why it's being denied permission. In any case, the error is either: permission denied, invalid mode or filename. (Tried it with double quotes as well).

Comment: I can see why it didn't worked...I didn't typed .txt file type. What a terrible mistake. No wonder it didn't work, however as I changed to Linux it could still be something else.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem, "invalid mode or filename". https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

write

```
'D:\ne_10m_airports' as 'D:/ne_10m_airports'
```

(change with uri formalism) or

```
'D:\\ne_10m_airports'
```

(escaping) or

```
r'D:\ne_10m_airports'
```

(r means raw string)